# jQuery to get the text attribute of a checkbox

Tags: asp.net, jquery, checkbox

I'm adding a check box to a page using the following statement;

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load ( object src, EventArgs e ) 
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
         CheckBox XChkBox = new CheckBox(); //instance of System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox
         XChkBox.ID = "someId"
         XChkBox.Text = "someText"
         somePlaceHolder.Controls.Add(XChkBox);
        }
    }
</script>
```

I need to get the Text attribute of that check box on click. I tried `$(this).attr('Text');` inside `$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){});` but it returns undefined.

Where am I going wrong? Please suggest.

cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

ASP .NET renders the `Text` property of the `ASP:CheckBox` server control, as a `label` element just after the `<input type="checkbox" />` on the generated markup at the client, it looks something like this:

```
<input id="someId" type="checkbox" name="someId" />
<label for="someId"> someText </label>
```

You can get the `text` of the `label` by:

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
  var $label = $(this).next('label');
  alert($label.text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `CheckBox` control renders the `Text` inside a `<label>` element.  The text is not part of the HTML checkbox.  If you want to get the text from jQuery, you have to get it from the `<label>`.

Also, the `<label>` it generates doesn't actually have an ID.  If your `CheckBox` is named `checkBox1`, then the HTML it outputs will be `<label for="CheckBox1">`, and the text is inside that element.  I believe the correct jQuery syntax would be:

```
$('label[for="checkBox1"]').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you're implementing what you call "text".

If it's like this:

```
<input id="chkFoo" type="checkbox" text="Check me, fool!" />
```

Then you can access the text like this:

```
$("#chkFoo").attr("text")
```

If you do it like this

```
<input id="chkFoo" type="checkbox" />Check me, fool!
```

I think you're out of luck. Put a span around the text if you have to do it this way and grab it like this:

```
<input id="chkFoo" type="checkbox" /><span id="spnFoo">Check me, fool!</span>

$("#spnFoo").text()
```

Comment: There's no `text` attribute or element content for checkboxes.

Comment: But you could add an attribute to the element and still access it from jQuery.