# Get the Text from asp:CheckBox

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I want to get the text of the `asp:CheckBox` using **JavaScript**.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chkRoles" runat="server" Text="Testing" onclick="javascript:test(this);" />
```

How to retrieve the text `Testing` from the checkbox? I have tried the following,

**JavaScript**

```
function test(obj)
{
    var text = obj.value;
}
```

Comment: You have tagged this incorrectly. `<asp:CheckBox` is WebForms, not MVC

Comment: I wrongly clicked the tag... thanks

Comment: No jQuery. Only plain JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `checkbox.nextSibling.innerHTML` in javascript as shown below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeCheckboxText(checkbox) {

            if (checkbox.checked) {
                alert(checkbox.nextSibling.innerHTML);
            }
        }
    </script>
```

> The nextSibling property returns the node immediately following the
>   specified node, in the same tree level.

Code :

```
CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
chk.ID = "chkRoles";
chk.Text = "Check";
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(chk);
chk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "changeCheckboxText(this)");
```

Also using jQuery :

```
$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
  var $label = $(this).next('label');
  alert($label.text());
});
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983863/jquery-to-get-the-text-attribute-of-a-checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

If you add ClientIDMode="Static" your Id doesn't change on client side.

```
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRoles" runat="server" Text="Testing" ClientIDMode="Static" onclick="javascript:test(this);" />
```

and you can do it with jquery like this

```
 function test(obj) {
        alert($(obj).next("label").html());
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

May this code will help you out:

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    function GetSelectedItem()
    {
    var text;
       var CHK = document.getElementById("<%=chkRoles.ClientID%>");
       var checkbox = CHK.getElementsByTagName("input");
       var label = CHK.getElementsByTagName("label");
       for (var i=0;i<checkbox.length;i++)
       {
           if (checkbox[i].checked)
           {
               text = label[i].innerHTML;
               alert("Selected = " + label[i].innerHTML);
           }
       }
       return false;
    }
    </script>
```